# Xcode, how to expand all collapsed loops in the source code view?

Tags: xcode

if you collapse the view of a loop (so that it shows the ellipses ... instead of the lines inside the loop) and you do this for many loops, is there a way to quickly expand all of them back to showing all lines of code again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to menu-->editor-->Code Folding-->Unfold all

Answer (score 12):

`Command + option + shift + <-`      for collapse code

`Command + option + shift + ->`      for expand code

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 12.4:

`Command + option + <-` to collapse code

`Command + option + ->` to expand code